# Edit new added Row in JTable

Tags: java, swing, popupmenu

i added a Row in my JTable with this popupmenu:

```
    final JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
    JMenuItem addItem = new JMenuItem("Add Movie");
    JMenuItem deleteItem = new JMenuItem("Delete Movie");

    addItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("test");
            Object frame = null;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) frame, "Movie wurde hinzugefügt!");

            model.addRow(new Movie("", 0, "", "", null, "DE"));
        }
    });
    deleteItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Object frame = null;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) frame, "Movie wurde gelöscht");
        }
    });

    popupMenu.add(addItem);
    popupMenu.add(deleteItem);
    table.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);
```

But alway, when i try to edit the values in this row i get an Error-Message.
Does anybody know why?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-3" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid range
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.rowsUpdated(DefaultRowSorter.java:896)
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.rowsUpdated(DefaultRowSorter.java:915)
at javax.swing.JTable.notifySorter(JTable.java:4264)
at javax.swing.JTable.sortedTableChanged(JTable.java:4118)
at javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(JTable.java:4395)
...
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Is model a a DefaultTableModel or one you've created yourself?

Comment: It is a custom model. See the OP's last question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/19877649/131872) for more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't implement the addRow() method properly.

You need to add the Movie object to your movie List and then invoke fireTableRowsInserted(...).

Check out [Row Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/). The RowTableModel class will give you an idea of how to implement the addRow() method.